# How to group paths by nodes or node labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a cypher query such as the following:

```
match a = (bs:BodyStructure {Name:"Brain structure"})<-[fs:Finding_site]-(dis:Disorder)-[r:Causative_agent]->(p) return a
```

How might I modify it to return a count of paths for each `p`, or the count of paths for each label of `p`?

(In this example, `p` can be labelled as either `Substance` or `Organism`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the number of paths for each `p` node:

```
MATCH (:BodyStructure {Name:"Brain structure"})<-[:Finding_site]-(:Disorder)-[:Causative_agent]->(p)
RETURN p, COUNT(*)
```

To find the number of paths for each `p` label (I assume there can be at most one label for the `p` nodes):

```
MATCH (:BodyStructure {Name:"Brain structure"})<-[:Finding_site]-(:Disorder)-[:Causative_agent]->(p)
RETURN labels(p)[0] AS label, COUNT(*)
```

*In the above RETURN statements, `COUNT(*)` is simply counting the number of matched rows that have the given aggregate key (`p` or `label`).*